# Replace higher order derivatives given lower order derivative

Tags: replacement, calculus-and-analysis

I have an unknown function `f[x1,x2]` whose partial with respect to `x1` is identically zero. I would like to make sure that whenever `D[f[x1,x2],{x1,2}]` shows up, for instance, it is evaluated to zero. How might I do this? Right now I have

```
conds = { Derivative[1,_][f][x1,x2] -> 0 };
D[f[x1, x2], x1, x2] /. conds // Simplify (* which equals zero, as I would like *)
D[f[x1, x2], {x1, 2}] /. conds // Simplify (* which is nonzero *)
```

Comment: Try `D[f[x1, x2], {x1, 2}] /. Derivative[k_Integer?Positive, _][f][__] :> 0` and report back.

Comment: This works exactly as I would like. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), this works:

```
D[f[x1, x2], {x1, 2}] /. Derivative[k_Integer?Positive, _][f][__] :> 0
```